# Как правильно сделать рефактор вот такому классу?

Tags: java, android

Есть класс диалога в который я передаю разные layout и он получился огромный так как каждый layout нужно обработать... Думал как то наследование исправить ситуацию но не могу догадаться как правильно его сделать

Вот класс

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
private static MyDialog dialog;
private EditText etNoteFromWeb;
private String text;
private int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt(States.LAYOUT);
    text = args.getString(States.TEXT);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    } else {
        Logger.log(MyDialog.class, "window == null", Logger.ERROR);
    }
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFragmentTheme)
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

    switch (layout) {

        case R.layout.dialog_bad:
            Button llBadOkCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bBadOkCamera);
            llBadOkCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_time_is_out:
            Button llOkCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.llOkCamera);
            llOkCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_did_not_finish_photo:
            Button bBackCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bBackCamera);
            Button bStartNewCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bStartNewCamera);
            Button bContinueCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bContinueCamera);

            bBackCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bStartNewCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bContinueCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_still_not_finish:
            Button bBackMain = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bBackMain);
            Button bStartNewMain = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bStartNewMain);
            Button bContinueMain = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bContinueMain);

            bBackMain.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bStartNewMain.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bContinueMain.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_reload_photo:
            Button bLater = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bLater);
            Button bSentNow = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bSentNow);

            bLater.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bSentNow.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_forgot_password:
            TextView tvPopText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvForgotPasswordPop);
            if (!UtilClass.isTextEmpty(text)) {
                tvPopText.setText(text);
            }
            Button bForgotPassword = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bForgotPassword);
            bForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_note:

            etNoteFromWeb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);

            Button bSent = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bSent);
            Button bSkip = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bSkip);

            bSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_instuction:
            Button bOkInstruction = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bOkInstruction);
            bOkInstruction.setOnClickListener(listener);

            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_invaite:
            Button bSms = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bSMS);
            Button bEmail = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bEmail);
            Button bOthers = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bOthers);

            bSms.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bEmail.setOnClickListener(listener);
            bOthers.setOnClickListener(listener);

            adb.setView(view);
            break;

        case R.layout.dialog_no_avatar_to_present:
            Button bOkPresent = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bOkPresent);
            bOkPresent.setOnClickListener(listener);
            adb.setView(view);
            break;
    }

    return adb.create();
}

private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String response;
        int viewId = v.getId();

        switch (layout) {

            case R.layout.dialog_bad:
                if (viewId == R.id.bBadOkCamera) {
                    dismissDialog();
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_time_is_out:
                if (viewId == R.id.llOkCamera) {
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.OK, R.layout.dialog_time_is_out);
                    dismissDialog();
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_did_not_finish_photo:
                switch (viewId) {
                    case R.id.bBackCamera:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.BACK, R.layout.dialog_did_not_finish_photo);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bStartNewCamera:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.NEW, R.layout.dialog_did_not_finish_photo);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bContinueCamera:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.CONTINUE, R.layout.dialog_did_not_finish_photo);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_still_not_finish:
                switch (viewId) {
                    case R.id.bBackMain:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.NOTHING, R.layout.dialog_still_not_finish);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bStartNewMain:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.NEW, R.layout.dialog_still_not_finish);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bContinueMain:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.CONTINUE, R.layout.dialog_still_not_finish);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_reload_photo:
                switch (viewId) {
                    case R.id.bLater:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.LATER, R.layout.dialog_reload_photo);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bSentNow:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.NOW, R.layout.dialog_reload_photo);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_note:
                response = etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();
                switch (viewId) {
                    case R.id.bSent:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(response, R.layout.dialog_note);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bSkip:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(null, R.layout.dialog_note);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_forgot_password:
                if (viewId == R.id.bForgotPassword) {
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(null, R.layout.dialog_forgot_password);
                    dismissDialog();
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_instuction:
                if (viewId == R.id.bOkInstruction) {
                    dismissDialog();
                    ;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_invaite:
                switch (viewId) {
                    case R.id.bSMS:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.SMS, R.layout.dialog_invaite);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bEmail:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.EMAIL, R.layout.dialog_invaite);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bOthers:
                        onClick.onDialogClickListener(States.OTHERS, R.layout.dialog_invaite);
                        dismissDialog();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.layout.dialog_no_avatar_to_present:
                dismissDialog();
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dismissDialog();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

private void dismissDialog() {
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    dialog = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}

public interface OnButtonClick {
    void onDialogClickListener(String response, int layout);
}

private OnButtonClick onClick;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if ((activity instanceof ActivityAuthorization) || (activity instanceof ActivityMain) || (activity instanceof ActivityCamera)
            || (activity instanceof ActivityFriendsCards)) {

        try {
            onClick = (OnButtonClick) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
        }
    } else {
        Logger.log(MyDialog.class, "Activity don't belong to any matches", Logger.ERROR);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClick = null;
}
}
```

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Извиняюсь за лишнее до*ебывание, но у вас в кейсе имеется "invaite"
переименуйте в "invite"

Comment: onClic преобразовать в интерфейс что-то типа OnClicInterface и вызывать функцию непосредственно оттуда для каждого параметра, также и для onCreateDialog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Создать базовый класс `BaseDialog`, в котором реализовать методы общие для всех диалогов.
2. Убрать двойной вызов `setView` для билдера.
3. Убрать статическую переменную dialog. У `DialogFragment` есть метод `getDialog()`.
4. Создать как положено несколько классов для каждого layout'а, отнаследовавшись от `BaseDialog`, избавиться от всех `switch (layout)`.
5. Убрать из аргументов `States.LAYOUT`, да и `States.TEXT` нигде не заполняется, в частности `newInstance` заполняет только layout.
6. `onAttach(Activity activity)` - deprecated. Следует использовать `onAttach(Context context)`.
7. В `onAttach` проверять контекст надо на инстанс `OnButtonClick`, а не перечислять все возможные активити в проекте. Тогда и ловить `ClassCastException` не придется.
8. Проброс в активити кликов с константами лучше заменить на вызов соответствующих методов в интерфейсе. Во-первых, вы не гарантируете (нет контракта), что активити обработает необходимый клик (что-то обработает, что что-то может пропустить), во-вторых, в колбэках у вас передаются разнородные данные, и в третьих, видимо, в активити опять есть кейс по layout'у... бррр.
9. Если клики можно сгруппировать по смыслу (по layout'у) то разделить `OnButtonClick` на несколько интерфейсов.
10. По мелочи. `handler` в `onDismissDialog` можно заменить на `getActivity().runOnUIThread()`.

Comment: Да все получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: Юрий а можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема я поменял `onAttach(Activity activity)` на `onAttach(Context context)` и у меня при создании класса этот метод вообще игнорируется... Если меняю на старый с `Activity activity` то срабатывает... Вы знали это?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Могу только предположить, что ваш DialogFragment из пакета android.app.Fragment и на девайсах с версиями api ниже 23 `onAttach(Context)` вызываться не будет, только `onAttach(Activity)`. Для фрагментов (подразумевалось) из библиотеки поддержки (android.support.v4.app) `onAttach(Context)` вызывается на любой версии api.

Comment: Фрагменты появились в api 11, с тех пор многое менялось, чуть ли не в каждой новой версии что-то дописывалось и как оно будет работать на разных девайсах с разными версиями и чем будет отличаться поведение проверять не хочется. Поэтому рекомендую перейти на библиотеку поддержки, если конечно у вас не микроприложение (без библиотек) для конкретной версии api...

Comment: Нет, я использую библиотеки в своем проекте. Но, что значит перейти на библиотеку поддержки? не совсем понимаю... Я использую в своем проекте `support library` но как на нее перейти в конкретном примере?

Comment: проверьте импорты. В данном случае если у вас есть `import android.app.DialogFragment;` змените его на `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`